# No Views in Document Library Web Part Sharepoint 2016

Tags: document-library, view

I'm attempting to make a Document Library that has three views. The three of these views work fine, but when I add it as a Web Part (or App Part) into a Wiki Style page, there doesn't seem to be a way to change the views that exist.  I was reviewing one of the Lynda vieos on Sharepoint 2016, which looks different from my environment:

[image: This environment has the options I want, taken from Lynda.com]

The environment I have doesn't have the ability to quickly switch views.  What am I doing wrong and what can I do to add the buttons to quickly switch between views?

Picture of my web part:

[image]

Comment: To clarify: I've looked in the settings for the web part and I don't see anything that gives me the option to switch views. I was able to enable to the search box, but that isn't nearly as important to the functioning of this document library as being able to specify particular, pre-configured views.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a function of the new Sharepoint 2016. In order to regain the menus I'm looking for, you have to return the Document Library to the "Classic" View. To do so:

1. Go to Site Contents
2. Select your Document Library
3. When it loads, click the gear in the top right corner, then choose 'Library Settings'.
4. Click on Advanced Settings.
5. At the bottom of this page, there will be a 'List Experience' option. Click the 'Classic Experience' Radio, then hit 'OK'. This will enable the toggling of custom views.